# Interacting Lagrangian - Coupling constant and cutoff factor

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, dirac-equation, regularization

I have a general question concerning a given interacting Lagrangian:

$$\mathfrak{L}_I = \frac{g}{\Lambda^2} \bar{\chi} \ \gamma^\mu \gamma_5 \ \chi \ \partial^\nu F_{\mu\nu}$$

where $F_{\mu\nu}$ is the electromagnetic field strength tensor. $g$ is a coupling constant and $\Lambda$ a cutoff-scale.

My question is pretty simple: What do the coupling constant and cutoff scale actually describe? Why is it necessary to introduce them?

Comment: The Lagrangian has a certain unit, and so do the different factors in it. For this case you need a mass-scale 1/mass$^2$ =$1/\Lambda^2$ in front to make the units come out correctly (= mass$^4$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't write comments right now So here is what i wanted to write

Coupling constant's value is an indication of how strong or weak the intraction and also for ascribing correct dimensions to lagarangian( as mentioned by @winther) is i.e an interaction  lagarangian of two particles with higher value of coupling constant will result in stronger interactions and also the masss dimensions of lagarangian will determine (well partially at least)whether theory is power counting renormalizable or not

considering renormalizibility for regularization and renormalization you have to include a cutoff to. It means you are limiting your integating varible values to some limit